# Integrate Uber api in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uber-api

I want to integrate Uber API in the react-native app. but they have not provide any SDK for react-native. I have used curl for ajax calls. GET `/products` are working fine. But there is getting some problem at 
GET `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize`

My sample code:

```
return response = fetch('https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=egkTW9gypag3ja3Qp0EyEWBhi4xN-DsN&scope=all_trips+delivery+history+history_lite+places+profile+request+request_receipt+ride_widgets&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:9000/login', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {},
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    alert(responseJson);

    this.setState({
      uberData: responseJson.products
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    alert(error);

  });
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-uber](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber) or [uber-api](https://github.com/nathanpdaniel/uber-api). There is no difference between sdk for  reactnative or nodejs.